# How to show a loading icon until the pdf file loads in an iframe

Tags: jquery

I have series of PDF files links in one page.  When user clicks any of them, a new windows opens up with with header and footer and an `<iframe>`. Inside that IFRAME, I am loading that PDF file.

Now PDF file is taking time to load, I want to show a loading icon until PDF file has completed loading.

By using my code the browser hiding the loading icon hides the loading when the Iframe is loaded. So need your help how to determine when Pdf is ready or loaded in Iframe.

code

```
$("#iframe").load(function(){  //Iframe is the id of Ifrmae
    $("#loadingicon").hide();  //loadingicon is id of the Loading Icon div
    $("#iframe").show();
});
```

Comment: in this case, the loading icon is hsowing till the iframe gets load. but my requirement is its hould stay till the pdf get loadinside that iframe

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you right off the bat that you're not using the .load method correctly.

.load is for ajax requests or to quote the docs

> > Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

Now if you were loading a url like

```
$("#iframe").load('/pdf.pdf');
```

then it makes sense.

To show if something is loaded yet like this you would do something like

```
$('#iframe').css('background', 'url(/spinny.gif)');
$("#iframe").load('/pdf.pdf');
```

That way the gif shows until the pdf is loaded from the server.

Comment: as my pdf fils are dynamic, so using this techniquqe. but not working

Comment: as my pdf srx are dynamic. so use this code but failed.<script>
$j(function() {
var location = $j('#iframe').attr('src');
$j('#loading').show();
$j('iframe').attr( 'src', location);
$j('iframe').load('location', function() {
$j('#loading').hide();
$j('iframe').show();
});
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you expected.

```
   $("#loadingicon").show();
   $("#iframe").hide(); 

    $('#iframe').load('\file.pdf', function() {
      $("#loadingicon").hide(); // this calls after load completes
      $("#iframe").show(); 
    })
```

Comment: what is this #result. If its a Div contain The Iframe, dont you think the function will run when result is loaded nomatter the pdf is loading or not. May be silly, but asking

Comment: as my pdf files are dynamic, so using this techniquqe. but not working

Comment: <script>
$j(function() {
var location = $j('#iframe').attr('src');
$j('#loading').show();
$j('iframe').attr( 'src', location);
$j('iframe').load('location', function() {
$j('#loading').hide();
$j('iframe').show();
});
});
</script>